# SpagoBI Server Scheduler fails to send a mail

Tags: spagobi

I did not get any mail from spagobi server to my mail id after scheduling the reports on the server. I use spagoBI 5.2 version. Below is the error message when i explored the spagobi.log file,

[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] 27 Jun 2016 00:19:12,368 ERROR it.eng.spagobi.tools.scheduler.dispatcher.UniqueMailDocumentDispatchChannel.sendFiles:409 -
Error while sending schedule result mail
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: mailtrap.io;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: mailtrap.io

Do i need to configure anything on MAIL category under configuration Management like smtp hostname, id some like that on spagobi server, if so , could anyone support me by giving the proper assistance. ?.

Regards,

Abdur Rahmaan

Answer (score 0):

See the doc http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/export/spagobi_server/Configure_v3?format=pdf , specifically the mail server section .

In SpagoBI server, tools -> manage configuration, there are three profiles which have SMTP configuration . Those are user, scheduled, and kpi_alarm. You'll need to update those with your SMTP settings.